# Axios post with proxy on create-react-app hosting server doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have following line in my package.json (react app)

```
"proxy": "http://www.demoapp.com"
```

I'm requesting data using REST-API call

```
axios.post('/user_data', { // http://www.demoapp.com/user_data
        id:id
    })
    .then((response) => { 
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {

    });
```

Above code works fine if I use it in my local system, But if I build a project and upload into hosting server proxy doesn't work.

Anyone know the solution? I have checked in github also but not found proper solution.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is virtually meaningless. Inspect actual requests in browser dev tools network  for clues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should define your proxy in the axios config, if it should be applied globally for every requests, you can use this code to define the Global axios default https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.proxy.host = "http://www.demoapp.com"
axios.defaults.proxy.port = ...
axios.defaults.proxy.auth.username = ...
axios.defaults.proxy.auth.password = ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It worked :) 
But instead of "proxy.host" it mentioned in "axios.defaults.proxy.host" I have used "baseURL ("axios.defaults.baseURL")" as it mentioned in GITHUB link which you have provided :)

Comment: I am looking for global proxy solution which works on all of my files,not on only one as above.

Comment: From the documentation https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults : `You can specify config defaults that will be applied to every request.` so this configuration will be applied globally to every requests