# Axios TypeError: Cannot set property 'host' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to send requests from React app to Spring Boot server without allowing CORS.

It works if I set `proxy` in `package.json`, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203599/axios-post-with-proxy-on-create-react-app-hosting-server-doesnt-work/52205444) question and answer advises to set `proxy` of axios with

```
axios.defaults.proxy.host = "http://www.demoapp.com";
```

I tried adding it to different places, but I always got

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'host' of undefined
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Component from "./components/Component";
import axios from "axios";

//axios.defaults.proxy.host = "http://www.demoapp.com";  doesn't work

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Component />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`Component.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Component extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        //axios.defaults.proxy.host = "http://www.demoapp.com"; doesn't work
    
        axios.post(...);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>
                    Hello World!
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Component;
```

Axios dependency in `package.json`

```
"axios": "^0.21.1"
```

Output of this line

```
console.log(axios.defaults);
```

is

```
{
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "headers": {
        "common": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "delete": {},
        "get": {},
        "head": {},
        "post": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "put": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "patch": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    }
}
```

Why is there no proxy field? How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure if the proxy object is still allowed, but if so, the `proxy` object is not defined in the defaults object. So you would need to create the `proxy` object first: `axios.defaults.proxy = { host: "http://www.demoapp.com" };
`

Comment: @Chris i can do that, but i still can't access server endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it out with the `interceptors` method.

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "http://www.demoapp.com/";

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
 // Do something before request is sent
  config.url = baseURL + config.url;

  return config;
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

use like this way : 

axios.post({
 url,
 data,
 headers: { ...},
 params,
});
```

Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: I tried it. Still get  `has been blocked by CORS policy`.