# Cannot make a request using proxy in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to use a proxy in my package.json fille like this

```
{
  "name": "type-redux-toolkit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api/v1" //proxy is here
}
```

and then making a post request using axios like this

```
 const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", credentials);
      console.log(res);
```

now  if i just put the full url in the request it works but i want to use the proxy.

i deleted the package-lock.json file  and node_modules folder and restared the app  like some people say but nothing

Comment: Can you some other code related to the post request...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203599/axios-post-with-proxy-on-create-react-app-hosting-server-doesnt-work

Comment: if using fetch https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/